# Hibernate OneToMany relationship inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, join, one-to-many

I'm trying to simply filter out results based on the ID property of a child class in a OneToMany relationship, but Hibernate (4.1.9.Final) is generating a Left Outer Join instead of an inner join and thus returning results I don't want.

**Model:**

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORYID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "CATEGORYNAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORYID")
    @Filter(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER")
    private Collection<TestCase> testCases
...
}
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TESTCASE_NEW")
@FilterDef(name = "TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER", defaultCondition = "TESTRUNID in (:IDS)", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "IDS", type = "int") })
public class TestCase
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "TESTCASENAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "TESTRUNID")
    private int testRunId;
...
    }
```

**DAO:**

```
public List<Category> getAllCategoriesForTestRuns(List<Integer> testRunIDs)
    {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.enableFilter("TEST_RUN_ID_FILTER")
                .setParameterList("IDS", testRunIDs);
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM " + Category.class.getSimpleName());
        List<Category> result = query.list();
        return resul2t;
    }
```

How can I tell Hibernate to use an inner join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something as follows:

```
select c from Category c inner join c.testCases tc
```